# connection string vs2015 and acces 2016

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to make connection a database (*.accdb) with two tables to C# windows form application.
there are 2 form , one for login authentication and second form is for read and write into database ,
first form works perfectly with connection but second form have problem with connection

first form is :

```
namespace DatabaseManagment
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Emad\Documents\login.accdb";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                CheckConnection.Text = "connection successfull";
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
            }
        }
```

and second form is :

```
   private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connectionstr.Open();
            OleDbCommand commandwrite = new OleDbCommand();
            commandwrite.Connection = connectionstr;
            commandwrite.CommandText = "insert into DB(reactor,class,measure,validity) values ('" + txt_reactorcore.Text + "','" + txt_class.Text + "','" + txt_unitofmeasure.Text + "','" + txt_validitycriteria.Text + "')";
            commandwrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("saved");
            connectionstr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }

    }
```

and error is :
errorsytem.data.oledb.oledbexeption(0x8004005)

Comment: Are you trying to reuse the variable _connection_ defined in the first form? This is not possible neither recommended

Comment: I also changed the variable connection in second form but neither didn't work

Comment: Try to not close the connection in the first form, neither to (re)open it in the second form.

Comment: I tried to don't close the connection but didn't work

Comment: You should create a third c#-class which will use for db-connections. And use it everywhere in your program. Just make sure there is only one instance of it and it being instantiated first.

Comment: @Eli I have to do it in app config ? or add a new class ?

Comment: Connectionstrings should be stored in the app.config [(See MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) and retrieved in your C# code from the [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx) collection

Comment: Then, as a general rule, you create a new connection inside a using block, open it and use it. Exiting from the using block will close and destroy the connection. Never keep a connection open for the lifetime of your program

Comment: By the way, your problem is in the second form with its connection but you don't show the relevant code of this second form, just the open command is not enough to understand what happens here.